# Opening .tab files associated with .lbl files in ENVI

Tags: georeferencing, envi

I need to open .tab files containing location information of chandrayaan-1 HYSI dataset. It contains four ASCII columns: longitude, latitude, pixel and scanline data. I need to open the .tab file as raster containing two bands- longitude and latitude for creating GLT file for georeferencing the HYSI dataset. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .tab file can be easily opened in notepad. There you can decide which column information is required for your work and then read this file using python easily.

Then, write the required columns (latitude, longitude and pixel value) in an ascii file using python. It will become a normal ascii file containing lat lon and pixel value which you can directly convert into a raster file using "ascii to pixel" tool of ERDAS Imagine or ArcGIS. Then export it in any raster format.

Note: If you require then I can also provide you the code to convert .tab file to normal ascii file using python as I'm working on Chandrayan LLRI data. It has similar .tab and .lbl files.

Comment: Thank you @MAYANK SHARMA. The code would be really useful.